# Figuring out communication protocol

Tags: i2c, oscilloscope, protocol, 1-wire

Complete beginner trying to learn by doing here...

**Background:**

I have a wine cooler (for beer) that I want to remote control the lights on by adding a microcontroller.
I'm planning on using a ESP32 powered by borrowing 5V from the coolers controller unit.

The chip powering this PCB is a HOLTEK BS86D20A-3, https://www.holtek.com/documents/10179/116711/BS86B12A-3_C16A-3_D20A-3v140.pdf

[image: PCB of controller unit]
[image]

I noticed 2 pins named SCL and SDA, and thought I could use this I2C interface to control the lights (instead of simulating pressing the light button)

And since there is only 3 cables leaving this PCB and goes into the back wall of the cooler;

- 5V (RED)
- DATA (BLUE)
- GND (WHITE)

It must communicate with something that turns on the light, adjusts the temperature etc over this DATA cable.

So I bought an **Noname LHT00SU1** to try figure this out, which leads to the question below.

**Question:**

I started by soldering 2 cables to the SCL and SDA pins, then connected the LHT00SU1 to is, and this is the result in PulseView, with the I2C decoder:

[image: Pulseview]

And this is the output by attaching a probe to the DATA (BLUE) wire, and I guessed it's 1wire protocol (It's the only one I know):

[image]

What's the next step, how do I figure out how to decode this?

---

@brhans:
So it's 300us / 7 = 42.8571429.
Sorry, this is way out of my league, but I'm trying to learn...
42.85 can't be a baud rate right?

[image]

I've uploaded the two .sr files here (the "DATA" one I called 1wire):

https://anonfiles.com/L1O8R5Qeue/1wire_sr
https://anonfiles.com/tdP2R2Q7u1/i2c_sr

Comment: It would be a really good step if you could see which chips were connected to the SCL and SDA lines.

Comment: Try decoding that DATA line as async UART instead. That initial long low period could be a 'break' condition which is often used in UART protocols to indicate the start of a packet. You'll have to play around with word-length & parity settings, but 8N1 is usually a good starting point. For the baud rate, measure the time from the 2nd falling edge (after the long break) until the next rising edge and then divide by 7, because my guistimate is it's 7 bits long (and the longer high period afterwards is probably 3 bits).

Comment: @user253751 im pretty sure its connected to the HOLTEK BS86D20A-3

Comment: I think your baud rate calculation is inverted and should be 7 bits / 300 µs ≈ 23.3 kbits/s.

Comment: @Theodore So in that case the baud rate should be "23000" (or more exact "23333").
This gives me hex values such as "7E", "94", "95". So then question is then, how to get further and figure out what is what?

This line is both receiving and transmitting data.
It sends instructions such as "turn on light", "set temperature".
But it also receives current temperature .
Is this really supported over plain UART like this?

Comment: I think you need to try to increase the sampling rate on your logic probe to get better resolution on the time measurement. I was looking at the previous 'low' period, which looked like 7 bits (maybe) - the one you've highlighted looks more like 9 bits to me. 300us / 9 == 3.33us/bit == 30k baud rate. A common rate near that is 28.8k which is 34.7us/bit or about 312us for that 9-bit-ish period. Of course I could also be completely wrong about this being UART ...

Comment: @Linus oh they are not connected to anything else?

Comment: @brhans sorry I've been busy and will get back to this later this week, and I will also add more info in my initial post, I'm realizing it's missing some stuff.
Thank you all so much so far!